# wordpress rest api send empty json file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

excuse me :: my english writing is very bad :)) 
I am developing a wordpress plugin and i need to get some row from custom table by rest api and excel format.
by this codes, excel file create in wordpress root and query works, but i cant download this when request address,
when request address, excell file that downloaded is empty and just writing "resourse ... " in it
please help me, thanks

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints' );

function wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints() {

register_rest_route( 'api', '/output/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'wpc_somename_search_callback',
    'args' => array(
            'date' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                )
        )
));   
}

function wpc_somename_search_callback( $request ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $date = $request['date'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}tickets where inroute_id=16 and date='$date'";
    $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $jsonDecoded = json_decode( json_encode($list), true);

    $fileName = 'example.csv';

    $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');

    foreach($jsonDecoded as $row){

        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    print $fp;

    exit; 
}
```

my request is

```
http://yootaabmarine.ir/wp-json/api/output/?date=13970822
```

Comment: Hi, beware, `$request['date']` and `date='$date'` is an example of SQL Injection threat.

Comment: thank you, What should I use instead of?

Comment: I haven't used Wordpress since a long time now, but I guess you will find a method in the `$wpdb` object that is used to escape SQL query parameters, so you will replace `date='$date'` with something like `date=" . $wpdb->escape($date);`. It will generate the `'` for you and escape the string against SQL injections.

Comment: ankabout :: I think I should use sanitize_text_field() or Something like this. Thank you very much for your guide. I just thought of getting the result and not sensing the database security

Comment: No, I don't think `sanitize_text_field()` is what you need, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks for prepared SQL queries, or use (wpdb::_real_escape( string $string ))[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/] if you find it simpler for you, just note if you use `wpdb::_real_escape()` you will need to add the `'`, example: `date='" . $wpdb->_real_escape($date) . "'";`.

Comment: how's it :: $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "select * from {$wpdb->prefix}tickets where inroute_id=%d and date=%d", 16 , '$date' ) );

Comment: Sorry don't have time to read the doc, but it looks fine except that we usually use `%d` for number replacement and `%s` for string replacement, and since dates are in form of strings, so you must use `%s` instead of `%d` for date: replace `date=%d` with `date=%s`.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me time. I'm losing ground for this Excel output for a few days. I hope you never get into trouble and your work will end very quickly ... thanks

Comment: Man, there is no problem, hope you may find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Well Ill try to help you, first why you are encoding then decoding the `$list` that's absolutely unnecessary and waste of processing... Well just before doing it can you `var_dump($list); exit;` and see what it's giving to you?

Comment: For the "resourse ... " that is normal, remember that `$fp` contains a resource, which is a PHP type in its own (see in the doc [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function return type is `resource`, and a resource is completely different from string, so you can't use `print $fp;`.
You can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to correctly output a file to the browser, it takes the file path as the first parameter and see the doc's first example to see the `header()`s you should use to correctly output a file to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `$jsonDecoded = json_decode( json_encode($list), true);` is useless in your code, you are transforming an array to a JSON string and then transforming it back to an array, it is better to use `$list` directly.

`$fp` contains a resource, which is a PHP type in its own (see in the doc [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function return type is `resource`), and a resource is completely different from a string, so you can't use `print $fp;`.

We could use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to correctly send a file to the browser, here is a solution:

```
function wpc_somename_search_callback( $request ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $date = $request['date'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}tickets where inroute_id=16 and date='$date'";
    $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $fileName = 'example.csv';

    $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');

    foreach($list as $row){

        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName .'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
    readfile($fileName);

    exit; 
}
```

Beware of SQL injections, use [prepared queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) instead.

Comment: hi ankabout, Sorry i replied late to you :: this workkkkk , yessss, i love youuuu. I should use readfile instead print. I will never forget this help.

Comment: hi @novintech no problem i'm really glad i helped you :)